# Bulk protein annotation with Prokka

Tags: functional-annotation

Can prokka be used to annotate a set of protein sequences (so bulk protein annotation), or does it require an entire genome for the annotation?

I've been looking through the documentation but haven't found a clear answer to this. I tested it, and the annotation of my protein sequences worked, but I wanted to check if the program expected a genome and that I can trust the output.

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Prokka doesn't need whole genomes, I've definitely used it for smaller contigs before so I think you're fine!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that's great!